# How to remove a extension from vendor folder?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I installed an extension using this command:

```
composer require magestore/module-bannerslider
```

The installation went ok, but now I do not want to use the extension anymore because it is giving compilation errors. I tried removing the folder magestore/bannerslider from the vendor folder, but this results in an error during upgrade. I checked the tables **core_config_data** and **setup_module** for entries from that extension, but there arent any.

So, how can I remove that extension or any extension that resides in the vendor folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
composer remove magestore/module-bannerslider
```

After that, run setup & compile commands

Comment: You welcome @Arnie

Comment: its showing "mageplaza/module-smtp is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed"

Comment: Same issue occur ...any solution founnd @SagarParikhSGR

Comment: You'd post a new question better, with your concrete details